# Get Polynomial X at Y? (Python 3.10, NumPy)

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

I'm attempting to calculate all possible real X-values at a certain Y-value from a polynomial given in descending coefficent order, in Python 3.10. I want the resulting X-values to be provided to me in a `list`.

I've tried using the `roots()` function of the `numpy` library, as shown in one of the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827053/solving-for-x-values-of-polynomial-with-known-y), however it does not appear to work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    coeffs = np.array([1, 2, 2])
    y = 1.5

    polyDataX = np.linspace(-2, 0)
    polyDataY = np.empty(shape = len(polyDataX), dtype = float)

    for i in range(len(polyDataX)):
        polyDataY[i] = coeffs[0] * pow(polyDataX[i], 2) + coeffs[1] * polyDataX[i] + coeffs[2]

    coeffs[-1] -= y
    x = np.roots(coeffs).tolist()

    plt.axhline(y, color = "orange")
    plt.plot(polyDataX, polyDataY, color = "blue")
    plt.title("X = " + str(x))
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
    plt.clf()

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

In my example above, I have the coefficents of my polynomial stored in the local variable `coeffs`, in descending order. I then attempt to gather all the X-values at the Y-value of `0.5`, stored within the `x` and `y` local variables respectivelly. I then display the gathered X-values as the title of the shown plot.

The script above results in the following plot:
[image]

With the X-values being shown as `[-2.0, 0.0]`, instead of the correct:
[image]

What is the proper way to get all real X-values of a polynomial at a certain Y-value in Python?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be making use of the [`numpy.polynomial.Polynomial`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial) class that was added in numpy v1.4 (more information [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html)). With that class, you can create a polynomial object. To find your solution, you can subtract `y` from the `Polynomial` object and then call the `roots` method. Another nice feature is that you can directly call the object, which you can use to compute `polyDataY`.

Just note that the `Polynomial` class expects the coefficients to be given backward from `np.roots`, i.e. a quadratic of `x^2 + 2x + 2` should have the coefficients `(2, 2, 1)`. To keep things consistent with what you gave, I just pass the reversed `coeffs`.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

coeffs = np.array([1, 2, 2])
poly = Polynomial(coeffs[::-1])

polyDataX = np.linspace(-2, 0)
polyDataY = poly(polyDataX)

y = 1.5
x = (poly - y).roots()
plt.axhline(y, color = "orange")
plt.plot(polyDataX, polyDataY, color = "blue")
plt.title("X = " + str(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct and you are using the root function correctly. There is only a small issue with datatypes.
You can see the error with a debugger or by printing `coeff` after `coeffs[-1] -= y`. At your line `coeffs = np.array([1, 2, 2])`, numpy will create the array with an integer type and therefore your subtraction, which should result in `0.5` actually results in `0`, so your coefficients become `[1, 2, 0]`. For those, the correct result is calculated. So we need to simply set the dtype to float:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    coeffs = np.array([1, 2, 2], dtype=float)   #<-----------
    y = 1.5

    polyDataX = np.linspace(-2, 0)
    polyDataY = np.empty(shape = len(polyDataX), dtype = float)

    for i in range(len(polyDataX)):
        polyDataY[i] = coeffs[0] * pow(polyDataX[i], 2) + coeffs[1] * polyDataX[i] + coeffs[2]

    coeffs[-1] -= y
    x = np.roots(coeffs).tolist()

    plt.axhline(y, color = "orange")
    plt.plot(polyDataX, polyDataY, color = "blue")
    plt.title("X = " + str(x))
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
    plt.clf()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, it worked. Just out of curiousity, what does the `coeffs[-1] -= y` line actually do? Does that shift the entire polynomial to make it so the `0` alligns with the value `y`, so we can calculate the roots? If so, why are we just changing the coefficents?

Comment: Solving the equation f(x) = y is equivalent to solving f(x) - y = 0, i.e., finding the roots. That's what's happening here when you subtract y.

Answer (score 1):

The values in `coeffs` are `int32` and the result after `coeffs[-1] -= y` is 0 not 0.5.

Just change `coeffs = np.array([1, 2, 2])` for `coeffs = np.array([1., 2., 2.])`